# Google 'Sign In' SDK in electron

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-api, sdk, electron

I'll get straight to the point:

I'm trying to make google sign in work in my electron app (written in React). I've been unsuccessful all the ay through:

Using SDK on front gives you `invalid cookiePolicy` error caused by Electron's custom way of implementing cookies (I've tried using npm packages that were supposed to help with that, but they are all outdated).

Using Google OAuth2.0 is just plain nightmare. However I've got to the point where I obtained access token. Though access token isn't what I need in my specific case (I require id_token).

I'm starting to lose my mind. Various big apps have google sign in implemented in them, anyone have any experiences on how to approach this?